# Datagrid in Compact Framework - format cell

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework

I would like to format (cell background color for a whole row) a gridview in Compact Framework.

It would not be something like alternating row style, but it would depend on some data the datasource has. So it's like ex.: one row out of total 4 rows for the dt.

What is the simplest way?

Do i need to override Paint() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [pretty extensive example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20268/NET-CF-Custom-DataGrid-Formatting) of customizing the CF DataGrid's formatting on Codeplex.